# Для чего нужен декоратор @staticmethod?

Tags: python

Не могу понять для чего нужен данный декоратор (@staticmethod)?
Ведь для создания статического метода достаточно не передавать аргумент self в создаваемый метод?
Или я не прав?

```
class qwe():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def test_nondec (value):
        return value * 10
    @staticmethod
    def test_dec (value):
        return value * 10
p_1 = qwe(10, 20)
print (qwe.test_nondec(10))
print (qwe.test_dec(10))
```

Comment: попробуйте вызвать эти методы для объекта класса.

Answer (score 3):

Если написать `p_1.test_nondec(10)`, то будет ошибка, а если `p_1.test_dec(10)` то все будет работать нормально